# Custom android spinner/picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, spinner, picker

I'm trying to add an android-like spinner to my mobile website. To put everyone in context the site is access via a WebView in an android application not from the phone/tablet browser.
Now the problem is adding a nice **jQuery android-like** spinner or spawning a **native control** that looks something like this:

Follow this [link](http://resources.deskactive.com/screen-shot.jpg) for image. Image taken from my phone on the Google calendar app.

I really don't want the solution posted [here](http://toddmhorst.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/android-like-date-picker-with-jquery-mobile-2/).

For several reasons:
- the plus button on top and bottom looks awful
- doesn't apply for other types of spinners that I have such as states (FL, CA, etc).
- I might need one, two or three spinners depending on the case

All those conditions completely discard the native DatePicker and I don't know if it's possible to get rid of the + things in it to make it look like the image above. If the case, that wouldn't solve the problem for the state spinner.

We also have an iPhone version of the app and we use cubiq spinning wheel but i don't want iPhone look-n-feel for the android version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one looks like a promising solution but I haven't tried yet.
http://mobiscroll.com/

Comment: yes that is one solution thanks. the other one i found and is the one i decided to use is http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/. Thanks!